# OpenCV Rotation with warpAffine in Python Causes Erroneous Border

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-rotation

Check out this Python code:

```
degrees = 90
center  = (24, 24)

img     = np.ones((48,48,3)) * 255
mat     = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, degrees, 1.0)
img     = cv2.warpAffine(img, mat, (48, 48))
```

My expectation is that a 3 channel, fully saturated, white square will be created and stored in img. After which, it'll be rotated by 90 degrees. Rotating a white square by 90 degrees should result in ... an indistinguishable white square. But when I:

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show(img)
```

I see an erroneous black border:

[image: What gives]

Is there any way to get `warpAffine` working as expected, i.e. rotate the image without an erroneous border? I've tried the following modifications to no avail:

```
center  = (23, 23)
center  = (24, 23)
center  = (23, 24)
center  = (25, 25)
center  = (24, 25)
center  = (25, 24)
```

Comment: What does it look like when you show it prior to the rotation? Clean? Also, what happens if you give it an odd number of pixel dimensions and can actually pick the center pixel as your center?

Comment: Prior to rotation, it's the expected clean square. Unfortunately, I cannot alter the images dimensions because in the dummy example above it's a white image--but my actual dataset is a CT scan where I'm trying to maintain dimension information.

Comment: Have you tried rotating about 24.5,24.5? It looks like getRotationMatrix2D accepts a Point2f so it should take the floats

Comment: @EastonBornemeier `(23.5, 23.5)` would be the center, indexing from 0 to 47 inclusive.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Good catch, that's what I meant, using the actual center of the image

Comment: Indeed @EastonBornemeier. Add it as the answer---it is correct, I verified.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds added, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the exact center of the image rather than the next closest thing. The rotation is slightly off center using (24,24).

Since `getRotationMatrix2D` accepts a Point2f, you should be passing the center as `(23.5,23.5)`, as it is the midway point between `0 and 47`.